# Subnetting with host part not zero

Tags: ip, system, ip-address, subnet

I am learning subnetting, I can subnet networks like 192.168.0.0 /16 /24 and so on.
Today I was given this exercise: subnet 192.168.0.1/16, I've never did a subnet on an address with non-zero host part. How am I supposed to do? I looked on Google but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent Q&A about subnetting [over at NESE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers) that you should read.

`192.168.0.1/16` is *not* a subnet address/prefix but a host address within the `192.168.0.0/16` subnet. *That* you could subnet, of course.